# Can't install Ubuntu 19.10 with MX230 - black screen

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, dell, 19.10

just got my brand new Dell Inspiron 14" 5000 (i7-10th gen, MX230) and I can't install Ubuntu 19.10. I disabled secureboot from the BIOS, legacy mode is no longer an option on this machine, and the nomodeset trick is not working for me: even with the string i just get a black screen and I have to kill the laptop. I'm pretty confident the issue here is the MX230, but as far as I know it should be fully supported by Ubuntu 19.10, am I right? Also, I can only get the "text" version of the installer, the one that should pop up with UEFI installations, but it is my understanding this should be ok.

Edit: With 18.04 LTS I'm able to get to the purple screen with Ubuntu and the five dots, after that it's black again and nothing happens.